# Target-Action parameter issue in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, target-action

I am following an iOS dev tutorial and reading their code. 
 First Code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let gestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(hideKeyboard))
    gestureRecognizer.cancelsTouchesInView = false
    tableView.addGestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer)
}
```

Second Code:

```
@objc func hideKeyboard(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) {
    let point = gestureRecognizer.location(in: tableView)
    let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForRow(at: point)
    if indexPath != nil && indexPath!.section == 0 && indexPath!.row == 0 {
        return
    }
    descriptionTextView.resignFirstResponder()
}
```

From what I understand, the first code enables keyboard disappeared when user tap anywhere on the screen.  To implement this, Target-Action pattern is hired.

In the first code, `#selector(hideKeyboard)`, hideKeyboard doesn't seems to have any parameter. So why there is a parameter in the helper function (second code).

If the parameter is valid, why is `gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer`?
I don't quite understand how does the parameter passing work?

Comment: Read the documentation for the superclass [UIGestureRecognizer](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uigesturerecognizer) for an explanation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `UIGestureRecognizer` always passes itself as the parameter to the `action` handler method.  It is fine to use `UIGestureRecognizer` instead of `UITapGestureRecognizer` in the handler routine since `UIGestureRecognizer` is a superclass of `UITapGestureRecognizer`, but what is passed in this case is actually the `UITapGestureRecognizer` instance.

If this handler routine isn't used by other `UIGestureRecognizer`s, I would write it like this:

```
@objc func hideKeyboard(_ gestureRecognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
```

This allows you to access properties of `UITapGestureRecognizer` that aren't common with the superclass.

The `selector` syntax is just using a shortcut syntax which is sufficient in this case to identify the method.  It could have used `#selector(hideKeyboard(_:))` to indicate that there is a parameter, but it isn't necessary.

Note that the parameter to the handler routine has to be the gesture recognizer.  You can't substitute another type, but you can leave the parameter off altogether in the handler routine if you don't need access to the gesture recognizer.